# Distance between section number and text in header

Tags: sectioning

With the `\subsection{My subsection}` the current sub-section numbers N.M and the string "My subsection" is produced like this: `N.M My subsection`. This is also displayed on the page header and in the TOC. How to change the horizontal space between the numbers N.M and the string: in the text, in the header and in the TOC at once? In the example below some more questions are written.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\geometry{paper=a5paper,left=15mm,top=20mm,hmarginratio=1:1,vmarginratio=3:1}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\cfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CO]{{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{{\thepage}}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily}{\thesubsection}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\sffamily}{\thesubsection}{0pt}{}

\setlength{\cftsecnumwidth}{1em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{1.7em}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{2.5em}

\begin{document}% ----------------------------------------------------

\section{My section}

Why nothing in header?

\clearpage

Two

\clearpage

Three

\clearpage

\subsection{My subsection}

Why there is `Number Space String`?

\clearpage

\subsubsection{My subsection}

Why we have a header below?

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: The distance between number and title is usually typeset by different commands in the title and in the toc. Moreover, it heavily depends on the class that you use as well as on certain packages. Therefore, provide the complete code of a small document that illustrates the problem.

Comment: The header at the TOC is created by the `tocloft` package. Strange.

Answer (score 3):

The page style `fancy` from the `fancyhdr` package defines the header as

```
\MakeUppercase {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@ \thesection \hskip 1em\relax \fi #1}
```

where `#1` is the section title. So the distance that you see there is `1em`.

The section heading is typeset by the `titlesec` package. You define it as

```
\titleformat{\section}{\sffamily}{\thesubsection}{0pt}{}
```

First, you use `\thesubsection` (probably `\thesection` intended). Since this is subsection 0 (no `\subsection` command yet) in section 1, you get the label `1.0`. Moreover, you define the distance between label and title as `0pt`, and this is what you see.

The commands `\cftsecnumwidth` etc are only relevant for the entries in the table of contents. The label `1` is put into a box of width `\cftsecnumwidth`. In the table of contents, the section is numbered "1" and not "1.0" since this time the `tocloft` package is in charge.

Altogether you have a confusing mix of packages. `fancyhdr` and `titlesec` may conflict in certain situations, in particular regarding running headers. It might also be better to load the `tocloft` package with the `titles` option such that the titles of table of contents, list of figures etc are controlled by the same package as the other headers.

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** I suggest to start from the following code and then to adjust what's not yet right.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage
  [paper=a5paper,
   left=15mm,
   top=20mm,
   hmarginratio=1:1,
   vmarginratio=3:1
  ]%
  {geometry}
\usepackage[sf,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{main}{\sethead{}{\thesection~\sectiontitle}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{main}
\begin{document}
\section{My section}
Why nothing in header?
\clearpage
Two
\clearpage
Three
\clearpage
\subsection{My subsection}
Why there is `Number Space String`?
\clearpage
\subsubsection{My subsection}
Why we have a header below?
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but the question remains: How to change the horizontal space between the numbers N.M and the string: in the text, in the header and in the TOC at once? If the combinations of these packages makes problems, what combination is secure?

Comment: @eipi10 I have added my suggestion for the code.